# wrong number of arguments calling `request` (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, cucumber

I am upgrading `cucumber-rails-0.3.2` to `cucumber-rails-1.3.1` and here is my `Gemfile`

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "cucumber-rails", "1.3.1", :require => false
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.8.1"
  gem "webrat"
end
```

I have login scenario, here it is

```
Scenario: Navigating to the login page
    Given an unauthenticated visitor

    When visitor goes to the home page
    And clicks on 'Login'

    Then visitor should see the people login page
```

and corresponding step definitions is

```
Given "an unauthenticated visitor" do
  request.session.delete if request && request.session
end
```

OR

something like this

```
request.session[:user_id].should == Person.find_by_username(user).id
```

in this stage, I am getting `wrong number of arguments calling request (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)`

I setup cucumber environments as per `cucumber-rails-1.3.1` and I am using `Mocks (RSpec::Mocks)`.

any ideas or help on this welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `request.session` object is really just a hash and [delete(doc)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete) expects 1 parameter(the key you want to delete delete).

Here is what your step definition should look like:

```
Given "an unauthenticated visitor" do
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
end
```

Comment: Can you please change "request.session.delete if request && request.session" with reset_session()? or Are you talking about Capybara.reset_sessions? Actually when I used "Capybara.reset_sessions" it's work

Comment: Still I am confusion, how about for this - request.session[:user_id] ?